# Fast and efficient iterator in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of words and would like to assign each of them a unique int value. I've read about LINQ for a while and came up with this:

```
var words = File.ReadAllLines(wordsFile);
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, words.Count());
var dict = words
    .Zip(numbers, (w, n) => new { w, n })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.w, i => i.n);
```

The question is:

1. Is this a good approach? Is it efficient in terms of performance?
2. Is there a better way to do this in terms of simplicity (clear code)?

Comment: `Select` already has an overload which gives you the index of each element, so you can drop the `Zip` and `Enumerable.Range` very easily...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `Enumerable.Range` and `Zip` approach since you can use the `Select` overload that gives you the index:

```
var dict = File.ReadLines(wordsFile)
    .Select((word, index) => new { word, index })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.word, x => x.index + 1);
```